# void pointer in function

Tags: c, function, void-pointers

I got a problem with void pointer in this program (I am sorry for having to bring up the whole <s>bad</s> program...).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void Input_int(int& InputVar, int Min = -2147483647, int Max = 2147483647);
void Output_array(void* Array, unsigned int ElementNumber, unsigned int Type = 0);
//Type = 0 => int, 1 => bool.
bool* Convert_decimal_to_binary(int n);

void main()
{
    int n;
    bool* binary;
    Input_int(n, -255, 255);
    binary = Convert_decimal_to_binary(n);
    printf("Binary's address: %d\n", binary);
    Output_array(binary, 8, 1);
}

void Input_int(int& InputVar, int Min, int Max)
{
    do {
        printf("Please input an integer in range [%d;%d]: ", Min, Max);
        scanf_s("%u", &InputVar);
        if (InputVar > Max || InputVar < Min) printf("Your number is out of the range!\n");
    } while (InputVar > Max || InputVar < Min);
}

bool* Convert_decimal_to_binary(int n)
{
    static bool Array[8];
    bool finishplus = false;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 0) Array[i] = 0;
            else {
                if (!finishplus)
                {
                    Array[i] = 0;
                    finishplus = true;
                }
                else
                    Array[i] = 1;
            }
            n = n / 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 0) Array[i] = 0;
            else Array[i] = 1;
            n = n / 2;
        }
    }
    return Array;
}
void Output_array(void* Array, unsigned int ElementNumber, unsigned int Type)
{
    if (Type == 0)
    {
        int* ArrayR;
        ArrayR = (int*)Array;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ElementNumber; i++)
            printf("Element %d got value: %d\n", i, ArrayR[i]);
    }
    else if (Type == 1)
    {
        bool* ArrayR;
        printf("Array's address (in Output_array) before type explicited: %d\n", Array);
        ArrayR = (bool*)Array;
        printf("Array's address (in Output_array) after type explicited: %d", Array);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ElementNumber; i++)
            printf("%d", i, ArrayR[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The main problem here is at the outputs of these 3 lines:

```
printf("Binary's address: %d\n", binary);
printf("Array's address (in Output_array) before type explicited: %d\n", Array);
printf("Array's address (in Output_array) after type explicited: %d", Array);
```

Why the 3rd output is different from the others?

Example:

> Binary's address: 11374900.
>   Array's address (in Output_array) before type explicited: 11374900.
>   Array's address (in Output_array) after type explicited: 1137490001234567.

there, `"01234567"` always appear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: What happens if you comment out the following: ArrayR = (bool*)Array;

Comment: Tagged C++ - Why `printf` etc? Also avoid `void` pointers as you lose type safety.

Comment: You forgot the `\n` on the last `printf` so it's appending the next number you output.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I added an example, not sure if it is what you suggested?

Comment: @EdHeal: I'm studying C.

Comment: @ntvy95 - So why is the question tagged C++? Will correct for you

Comment: @EdHeal: I tagged C but I don't know why it turned out to be C++. Maybe it is my mistake.

Comment: I suggest using `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` instead of relying on it to be 32 bits.

Comment: This question is too localized to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `\n` on the last `printf` so it's appending the next number you output. The pointer itself is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for being annoying..

Comment: @ntvy95, not annoying at all. It's easy to miss the simplest things.

Comment: It's also easy to look at one's program and notice the extremely obvious ... the program explicitly prints those numbers; they had to show up in the output *somewhere*.